# Is there a way in lua to define a function that will run if a file is required?

Tags: dependency-injection, lua, require

I would like to create a lua function early in a script that will then automatically get called if a matching filename is required but before that require is complete.

effectively it will go

```lua
if FILE then
   run before FILE is loaded
end

-- some other stuff

require"FILE"
```

If FILE is never required then the stuff in the if will never run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require` is just a function so you can redefine it.

```lua
$ cat foo.lua
real_require = require

function require(mod)
    if mod == 'string' then
        -- do something
        print('importing ' .. mod)
    end

    return real_require(mod)
end

require'string'
$ lua foo.lua
importing string
$
```

Comment: This looks fantastic. I'll try it out today and then mark as solution

Comment: Is there any way to expand this to know what sub module/arguments are being called? e.g. `require'string'.setup("file")` and have the custom require aware of the .setup part?

Comment: that's no possible. `require'string'.setup("file")` is the same as `mod = require'string'; mod.setup("file")`. `require()` cannot control how its return value will be used.

Comment: if you really want to control the `setup()` part then you can ask the new `require()` to also change the return value so you can redefine the `setup()` method too.